# Is lactose free chocolate milk still a good recovery drink

Tags: nutrition, training, muscle-recovery

So I have been weight training and doing a lot of cardio for five months now and after every workout I have my full cup of chocolate milk. Since I have a mild lactose intolerance issue I use lactose free milk.

Today I read something that mentioned that the most important component of this drink to restore the glycogen reserves is precisely the lactose which is milk's sugar.

Does this mean that I have been drinking a useless mix and should look elsewhere to get the right combination of protein and carbs for this purpose?

My workout program is weight training for about an hour three times per week and intense cardio between 30 and 60 minutes two to three times per week with the purpose of reducing my fat percentage which means reducing fat and increasing lean muscle mass, my objective is to get to somewhere between 12% and 15% of body fat.

Comment: Lactose free milk is made by adding lactase enzyme to it, which converts lactose into glucose, another type of sugar which you can digest.

Comment: Why would any kind of chocolate milk be a good recovery drink? Milk only has 8 grams of protein per cup. That's like one bite of a sausage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little research shows that lactose-free milk is made by adding lactase to milk, which breaks down the lactose into simpler sugars. If the brand you are drinking is like that, it will have no difference on your nutrition.

Answer (score 0):

Much of the important part of the milk after a workout comes from the fluids and protein, so it's not a waste. As for the sugar associated with the lactose, you could probably replace it with a piece of fruit which would also have other nutrients.